# Get data that do not exist in another table in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to find rows with user_ids in Product collection but not in ActivityUser collection.

I have 2 collections: 
**Product collection**

```
[
  { _id: “6483987fe5b1ba0028320e89”, 
   user_id: “6483987fe5b1ba0028320555” 
  },
  { _id: “6483987fe5b1ba0028320e89”, 
   user_id: “6483987fe5b1ba0028320888” 
 }
]
```

**ActivityUser collection**

```
     [{_id: “6483987fe5b1ba0028320e89”,     
      user_id: “6483987fe5b1ba0028320777”,
      activeTime: “”,
      module: “module”
      },     
      {_id: “6483987fe5b1ba0028320e89”,     
       user_id: “6483987fe5b1ba0028320901”,
       activeTime: “”,
       module: “module”
      },     
     ]
```

I want to get only this row:

```
[{ _id: “6483987fe5b1ba0028320e89”, 
   user_id: “6483987fe5b1ba0028320555” 
}]
```

Below is the code that I tried however I am getting empty results:

```
      const aggregate = [
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$user_id',
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'ActivityUser',
        localField: 'user_id',
        foreignField: 'user_id',
        'as': "activity"
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "activity.user_id": {
          $exists: false
        }
      }
    }
  ];
   const data = await ProductModel.aggregate(aggregate)
```

Comment: After your `$group` stage the only fields the document contains is `$_id`. As such the value of the `localField` for the lookup is empty (missing). But since `_id` is set to the value of `user_id` in the `$group` stage, you can change the `$lookup` to have `localField: '_id'` and it should work

Comment: @user20042973 I just tried that but I seem to be still getting empty.

Comment: Before I write an answer, let me take a step back and ask another question. The item that you are requesting seems to be a single document that is in the `Product` collection. What is the purpose of the aggregation overall? Should you instead just be issuing a simpler query only against the `Product` collection?

Comment: @user20042973 the results should be an array of products. I need to get products from Product collection with user_id that is not in ActivityUser collection.